# Can I use another port other than 443 for HTTPS/SSL communication?

Tags: https

443 port is typically used for HTTPS/SSL. But is it the only option we can choose for HTTPS/SSL communication. If not, why?

Answer (score 94):

The port number is not "magic", you can use any port from 1-65535 you like. There are only 2 conditions:

1. Both the server and the client have to (agree to) use the same port number.
2. Ports in the range 1-1023 are "well known ports" which are assigned worldwide to specific applications or protocols. If you use one of these port numbers, you may run into conflicts with the "well known" applications. Ports from 1024 on are freely useable.

As an example, you could use port 30443 for SSL VPN if your VPN gateway supports port reassignment and the SSL VPN client (if any) does this as well. If you access SSL VPN via web portal, you can add the custom port number in the URL like this: "https://mysslvpnserver.com:30443".
Beware that public internet feeds (hotels, hotspots) often block high ports > 1024.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you also share how to configure all https request to another port

Comment: yes, add a colon and the port number to the URL, for example "https://www.somedomain.com:8443".

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what i meant to ask is i have a port 1122 that i need to access via https am currently on centos how can i customize the server so as to allow https traffic on port 1122

Comment: @user1016274 thanks for answering in details. I'm using SSL from letsencrypt and using port 8687 for this. Letsencrypt try to validate ssl on port 443 port by default. This problem is related to well known applications. Do you've any Idea how I can fix this on server side? Like if my client change its SSL provider, there will no need to modify or setup any thing on provider's side. 
Thanks in advance for your answer sir :)

Comment: @Emanuel Paul Mnzava - firewall rules govern what traffic is allowed in and out of a server. You should try to setup a basic firewall that will accept new TCP connection requests on port 1122. [Here is a firewall tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-basic-firewall-template-with-iptables-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 56):

We can use any available port for HTTPS, however, for the sake of convention, 443 and 8443 are assigned for HTTPS (browsers automatically prefix with https when these port numbers are used), but we can even run HTTPS on port 80. In this case it is our responsibility to use https (if we don't indicate it, the browser will consider it a http link).