# Specifying a port with https domain

Tags: http, encryption, https

I am building a React Native app which currently uses port 3000 on a server to make Mongoose requests and more, like the below

```
http://<aws-ip-address>.compute.amazonaws.com:3000
```

If I'm not mistaken I have to use https, not sure if it was an Apple or Firebase requirement.

If I use something like

```
https://<aws-ip-address>.compute.amazonaws.com:443
```

Would that be valid? You are already specifying the 'https' part and then with the port you do it again? Does one override the other (e.g. in the case of https://.compute.amazonaws.com:5000 is it https or not, because it says 'https' but port is 5000)? Same question for 'http' and port 80

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/29414208/1816580

Comment: @ArtjomB. Partially. If I choose https://localhost:80, does that mean it is https or http? Would you need to make changes on the server side to have port 80 create an https connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity sake let's say that a URL looks like this:

```
scheme://fqdn:port/
```

The scheme (http or https) is independent of the port, but both http and https have default ports associated with them. You need both a scheme and a port to make a connection.

`http://fqdn/` is equivalent to `http://fqdn:80/` and
`https://fqdn/` is equivalent to `https://fqdn:443/`

Nowadays the browser defaults to http but some browsers will default to https when the scheme is omitted.

When entering `fqdn:443/` the browser will try to open `http://fqdn:443/` (for now but the default behavior is changing with different browser makers), but only if there is no HSTS record in the browsers cache for that fqdn.

When entering `https://fqdn:80/` the browser will use https as is defined and connect to TCP port 80. Of course, the server must be configured for TLS on that port and have a web server that speaks the http protocol behind that.